# Product matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Need help with following Error:

```
DoesNotExist at /sales_data/sales_data_import
Product matching query does not exist.
```

I have two models below, SalesData gets product name from Product. And I am trying to import csv with sales data to SalesData module through function, but it does not work.
And I am sure that all the products names in imported csv are included in model Product, so do not understand whey there is DoesNotExists Error.

**Models.py:**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Product", max_length=150)
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"

class SalesData(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField("Date", null=True, blank=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    sales = models.DecimalField("Sales", max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField("Quantity", null=True, blank=True)

    @classmethod
    def create_from_csv_line(cls, line):
        sd = SalesData()
        entry1 = line["Date"]
        entry2 = datetime.strptime(entry1,'%d.%m.%Y %H:%M') 
        date = entry2.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        sd.date = date
        status = str(line["State"])
        sd.status = status
        curr = str(line["Currency"])

        sd.product = Product.objects.get(name=str(line["Items"]))

        sd.quantity = int(line["Item quantity"])
        sales = float(line["Subtotal"])
        if curr == "CZK":
            sd.sales = sales * 100/(100+VAT)
        else:
            sd.sales = c.convert(curr, "CZK", sales, entry2) * 100/(100+VAT)
        if status == "fulfilled":
            sd.save()
```

**Views.py:**

```
class SalesDataImportView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, FormView):
    template_name = "sales_data/sales_data_import.html"
    form_class = SalesDataForm

    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.is_superuser

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form: SalesDataForm = SalesDataForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            csv_file = form.cleaned_data["uploaded_file"]  
            decoded_file = csv_file.read().decode('utf-8-sig')
            io_string = io.StringIO(decoded_file)
            reader = csv.DictReader(io_string, delimiter=",", skipinitialspace=True) 
            for line in reader: 
                SalesData.create_from_csv_line(line=line)
            context = self.get_context_data()
            my_text = 'New data uploaded successfully.'
            messages.success(request, my_text)
            return render(request, self.template_name, context)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error here:

```
sd.product = Product.objects.get(name=str(line["Items"]))
```

Error: `Product matching query does not exist`.

Try to debug. For example:

```
print(str(line["Items"]))
# before Product.objects.get
```

Probably the `str(line["Items"])` give you an name, which not exists in table `Product`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help, easy solution, error find. I would like to prevent this error in application, so I tried following:
try:
   sd.product = Product.objects.get(name=str(line["Items"]))
except:
   print(str(line["Items"]))
   sd.product = ""
But I am getting this error.:
Cannot assign "''": "SalesData.product" must be a "Product" instance.

Is there some way how to skip rows with missing product name?